# Нужно сделать скриншот в UWP приложении и сохранить?

Tags: c#, uwp

Приложение в магазине уже, но хочу сделать кнопку *Сохранить*.
Рендеринг мне не подходит, кроме того много трансформации и манипуляций в приложении. Рендеринг не видит изображение с `MediaElement`. Конечно, можно его сделать прозрачным на секунду и снимок получается, но с видео можно использовать картинки, а это очень важная часть. Если кто-то знает как, пожалуйста, помогите.

Заранее спасибо.